# The API is not returning a value that I know it should

Tags: support, api, paging

My "Meta Stack Overflow" site details are not listed in the API, when I use `meta_site;main_site` in the `types` parameter. See:

[/2.2/users/2855348/associated?types=meta_site;main_site](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/associated-users#ids=2855348&types=meta_site%3Bmain_site&filter=default&run=true)

But, if I filter for meta sites only (`types=meta_site`), I can see the "Meta Stack Overflow" details in the API result:

[/2.2/users/2855348/associated?types=meta_site](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/associated-users#ids=2855348&types=meta_site&filter=default&run=true)

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [API results are paged](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/paging), defaulting to 30 (base) records at a time.

So **you need to always check the `has_more` property and fetch additional pages, if needed.**

In your second query, it currently returns 22 records. So you see the "Meta Stack Overflow" result you expect.

However, in your first query, 46 records are available and, because you used the default paging of 30, only the first 30 are returned.

You will find the "Meta Stack Overflow" item in [**page 2 of those results**](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/associated-users#page=2&ids=2855348&types=meta_site%3Bmain_site&filter=default&run=true).